# Excluding "provided" libraries from MobileFirst Maven builds

Tags: maven, ibm-mobilefirst

I have added a `<scope>provided</scope>` dependency to my Maven `pom.xml` for my Java adapter, because the referenced jars are provided by my application server, but Maven install is still including the jars in the `.adapter` file.

Is this the expected behavior? Is this a Maven issue, or something related to MobileFirst platform foundations use of it? The MFP `provided` libraries seem to not be included.

Not included in `.adapter` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
        <artifactId>adapter-maven-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>8.0.2017012516</version>
    </dependency>
```

Included:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have a look at the dependency:list in Maven and verify that the dependency for commons-lang3 is indeed "provided". Maven dependency mediation might have changed it to "compile".

Comment: @JFMeier being a Maven novice, and using it from within Eclipse at the moment, I'm still trying to search/work-out how to give that a shot :-)

Comment: Ok, if I did this correctly, it appears commons-lang3 is provided:
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
...
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3:provided